# Azure DevOps Service - Authenticate with On-Premise ADFS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, adfs

All, The organization for whom I work requires on-premise AD and we currently use different trusts within ADFS to allow authentication to apps such as paycor, ppmpro, promapp, and others.

My question is: is it possible to authenticate to Azure DevOps (service in the cloud, not on-premise) using Active Directory Federation Services?  I have not tried any measures because I don't have access to our on-premise ADFS or AD environment. There is a lot of for Azure AD but nothing for on-premise AD and ADFS.

Any help greatly appreciated.

THanks,

-Greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can but it depends on whether you are already using Azure AD.

If you are using M365, you probably are using AAD Connect which syncs. users from AD to Azure AD.

Or you might be using [PTA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-pta)?

Users not in AD (and not synched up) can be added to Azure AD as guest accounts.